# Configure.ac options when building from source

Tags: osx, compilation

Disclaimer: newbie to emacs, vaguely competent on MacOS and git.

I'm building emacs on OSX Yosemite from the git master repo.  I've done this several times, primarily by using

`./configure --with-ns --with-imagemagick --with-rsvg --with gnutls`

with greater or lesser degrees of success, depending on current state of master.

However, I derived this config from lunaryorn's [excellent discussion of emacs on MacOS](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/what-is-the-difference-between-aquamacs-and-other-mac-versions-of-emacs) without really understanding what I'm doing.

I decide to take a look today at the `configure.ac` file to find out what compile options are actually available.  The relevant bits seem to be these:

`OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([xpm],[don't compile with XPM image support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([jpeg],[don't compile with JPEG image support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([tiff],[don't compile with TIFF image support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([gif],[don't compile with GIF image support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([png],[don't compile with PNG image support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([rsvg],[don't compile with SVG image support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([xml2],[don't compile with XML parsing support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([imagemagick],[don't compile with ImageMagick image support])`

`OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([xft],[don't use XFT for anti aliased fonts])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([libotf],[don't use libotf for OpenType font support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([m17n-flt],[don't use m17n-flt for text shaping])`

`OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([toolkit-scroll-bars],[don't use Motif or Xaw3d scroll bars])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([xaw3d],[don't use Xaw3d])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([xim],[don't use X11 XIM])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_OFF([ns],[use NeXTstep (Cocoa or GNUstep) windowing system])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_OFF([w32], [use native MS Windows GUI in a Cygwin build])`

`OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([gpm],[don't use -lgpm for mouse support on a GNU/Linux console])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([dbus],[don't compile with D-Bus support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([gconf],[don't compile with GConf support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([gsettings],[don't compile with GSettings support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([selinux],[don't compile with SELinux support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([gnutls],[don't use -lgnutls for SSL/TLS support])
   OPTION_DEFAULT_ON([zlib],[don't compile with zlib decompression support])`

From what I can tell, it seems that imagemagick et al are already being built by default, so I only really need to use the `--with-ns` flag.

1. Is that correct?
2. If so, are there any of these default_ON settings that I can turn off as not relevant (such as the X-related ones?)?
3. In regards to lunaryorn's config mentioned above, would I need to use those options for a `brew install` version of emacs?
4. Finally, any other tips on building from source?

Comment: You can check such things by looking at the summary printed by `configure` at the end. It lists which libraries ended up enabled/disabled. In my experience, `--with-ns` tends to disable X related things and unnecessary graphics libraries etc.

(Other tips? `mkdir my-build-dir && cd my-build-dir && ../configure --with-ns && make` to keep the main source dir clean.)