# "Mark all Misspellings" never stops

Tags: text-editing, spell-checking

On my Emacs (Aquamacs on OSX, latest version) the command Edit -> Spelling -> Mark All Misspellings goes through the whole file (from 0% to 100%) and then starts again at 0%, and continues ad infinitum.

The menu item runs the command flyspell-buffer
(found in global-map), which is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp
function in ‘flyspell.el’.

I cannot do anything else and have to abort Emacs to stop the command. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know Aquamacs, but you can improve your question with more information. What version of Aquamacs are you using? What command does that menu item run? (type `C-h k` and then select the menu item). Does the help for that command tell you anything useful about this issue? What does "go through the whole file" mean? (Is that an interactive process, or is it just cycling forever on a non-interactive progress/percentage message?) What does "abort the editor" mean? (`C-g` ?). If you're not closing the application completely, are there any helpful messages left in the `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: Lawlist mentiones there that especially the spell checking is where Aquamacs differs from GNU emacs. So you will only get help from aquamacs users (maybe lawlist?). http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/what-is-the-difference-between-aquamacs-and-other-mac-versions-of-emacs#comment-3818